# Debian Etch - Mercurial in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, debian, etch

I'm running a Debian Etch system with eclipse.
I installed mercurial plugin (http://www.javaforge.com/project/HGE) for eclipse indigo (latest version I guess). And I installed mercurial via the sudo apt-get command.
hg status result in

```
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 0.9.1)

Copyright (C) 2005 Matt Mackall <mpm@selenic.com>
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

In Eclipse I get the following error message

```
hg: unknown command 'debuginstall'
Mercurial Distributed SCM

basic commands (use "hg help" for the full list or option "-v" for details):

 add        add the specified files on the next commit
 annotate   show changeset information per file line
 clone      make a copy of an existing repository
 commit     commit the specified files or all outstanding changes
 diff       diff repository (or selected files)
 export     dump the header and diffs for one or more changesets
 init       create a new repository in the given directory
 log        show revision history of entire repository or files
 parents    show the parents of the working dir or revision
 pull       pull changes from the specified source
 push       push changes to the specified destination
 qdiff      diff of the current patch
 qimport    import a patch
 qinit      init a new queue repository
 qpop       pop the current patch off the stack
 qpush      push the next patch onto the stack
 qrefresh   update the current patch
 remove     remove the specified files on the next commit
 revert     revert files or dirs to their states as of some revision
 serve      export the repository via HTTP
 status     show changed files in the working directory
 strip      strip a revision and all later revs on the same branch
 update     update or merge working directory. Command line: hg -y debuginstall
```

Answer (score 3):

Mercurial version 0.9.5 is too old for HGE. You can try to install a newer version manually, but perhaps the python version in etch is too old also. In fact, [Etch is old](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianEtch), that is the main problem. You best chance, if you don't want to upgrade, is to use Mercurial by command line.

Comment: Okay thanks. I hoped that this would not be the only resolution. It was a lot of fun to get the latest Eclipse, JVM etc. running..

Comment: The strange point is that "debuginstall" was added in version 0.9.2, so you should have it in your version. You definitively have to try version 1.3.X or 1.4.X in a [user install](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UnixInstall#Per-user_installation) to not pollute your ancestral and venerable distro :-p

Comment: In fact, you will need [version 1.5 minimally](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mercurialeclipse/wiki/SupportedMercurialVersion)